# How can we solve getting snapshot for each child form when they're minimized?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms[i].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {

`Application.OpenForms[i].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Application.OpenForms[i].Width, Application.OpenForms[i].Height))
                {
                    Application.OpenForms[i].DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                    bmp.Save(@"d:\Duong\" + Application.OpenForms[i].Text + ".png");
                }
                Application.OpenForms[i].WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }
            else
            {
                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Application.OpenForms[i].Width, Application.OpenForms[i].Height))
                {
                    Application.OpenForms[i].DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                    bmp.Save(@"d:\Duong\" + Application.OpenForms[i].Text + ".png");
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Each Application.OpenForms[i] has a MdiParent. When some of them were minimized,some are actived, I clicked a button to get snapshot, I got all of the picture of each form. But any minimized forms had flashing appeared before getting back minimize. I know that trouble is come from WindowState, but how can I get snapshot if it doesn't show?..Please help me..I have seen topics about API GDI+..but they're for minimized application of window, what I just need now is for my form and it childs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to:

- suspend form drawing
- take snapshot
- resume form drawing

You can suspend/resume drawing using [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_SETREDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Suspend control drawing before your For cycle and resume drawing at the end of your code. I recommended to use a [Try/Catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and include resume drawing in the Finally section.

To suspend drawing:

```
SendMessage(ctrlControl.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0)
```

To resume drawing:

```
SendMessage(ctrlControl.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0)
ctrlControl.Refresh()
```

ctrlControl can be any control: in your case I recommend using the MDI container.

Comment: thanks for your reply..but I'm not a professional programmer..so It's hard for me to understand how these method using..please give me more details..or just an example if could..thanks

Comment: added details to my answer.

Comment: oh thanks god..you saved my life..finally I have found the best way to  solve it..I spent two days feeling exhausted with this problem..Thanks so much..but there one more question about your idea..why we must have try-catch block?..if we don't, what will cause errors?

Comment: just to prevent a situation where you suspend control drawing and an exception occured before resume it. in this case the control won't be refresh at all until you close your application.

Comment: I have an application that used suspend/resume drawing which is also installed on XP client and I never had any problem. If it works, please consider to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots of all minimized windows.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", Application.OpenForms.Count));

    System.Collections.IEnumerator myEnumerator = Application.OpenForms.GetEnumerator();
    while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Form current = (Form)myEnumerator.Current;
        if (current.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized )
        {
            current.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            current.Activate();

            Application.DoEvents();

            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(current.Width, current.Height))
            {
                current.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\childwindows\" + current.Text + ".png");
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. Best regards.

Comment: thanks for your help..but it still shows any child forms which were minimized..if I put "current.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;" at the last row in if-condition..it just appeared and disappeared..what i want now is minimized form not load back and I still get snapshot its..

Answer (score 0):

This wil restore the minimized windows and also take a snapshot of all other owned application windows.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

System.Collections.IEnumerator myEnumerator = Application.OpenForms.GetEnumerator();
while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Form current = (Form)myEnumerator.Current;
    if (current.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        current.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        current.Activate();
        Application.DoEvents();
        SaveToFile(current); 
        current.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    else
    {
        current.Activate();           
        Application.DoEvents();                
        SaveToFile(current); 
    }
}

}

private void SaveToFile(Form form)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height))
    {
        form.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\childwindows\" + form.Text + ".png");
    }
}
```

Hope this will help. Regards.

Comment: hmm..it also has GDI+ error because my current[0] can't be draw..but moreover, perhaps you didn't understand clearly my goal..I don't want to restore all minimized forms. I just want them do nothing but I still can draw it to image..really appreciate your help..